# How do processes know the addresses of shared library?

Tags: linux, kernel, dynamic-linking, shared-library

As far as my understanding goes, when I compile my C source code, GCC/LD does the address binding at compile time. Typically, this address starts at zero. When I call a function from shared library, how does the compiler know the address of the shared library in advance? I know shared libraries get their address at load time. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Searching for "dynamic linking" (which you already appear to know since you selected that tag) yields loads of information already. What specific questions do you have? (Covering the whole process is quite a task.)

Comment: suppose I called the printf() function. How the compiler will know the memory location of printf() function at compile time?

Comment: It doesn't, that's why it's called dynamic linking.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a few things to help yourself understand this.

`ldd /usr/bin/cat`

On my laptop, that gives this output:

```
1771 % ldd /usr/bin/cat 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc37fba000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1ea7018000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1ea73bc000)
```

You'll notice that `linux-vdso.so.1` and `libc.so.6` don't have a fully qualified path, and that `ldd` shows you what the actual path that would be used to dynamically link in `libc.so.6` is.

You can check that (and learn a bit) by doing the `ldd` again, with a little variation:

```
1790 % export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib
1791 % ldd /usr/bin/cat 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff0a5a0000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa257535000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa2578d9000)
```

Looking closely, you can see that the dynamic linker (`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` in this case) will now choose `/lib/libc.so.6` as the C library. So the enironment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is important to deciding which files actually get used in dynamic linking.

The other thing you can do is `strace`:

```
strace -o cat.trace /usr/bin/cat /etc/motd
```

The file `cat.trace` will have a record of what system calls your subject process performs. Some of them will be `mmap()` of the files shown by `ldd` as getting dynamically linked in. Follow up by googlling for `mmap`.

Further reading: `man ld.so`.

See if you have the `readelf` command installed, or if you can install it, or compile it. Run `readelf -a /usr/bin/cat`. The actual [ELF specification](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/ELF_Format.pdf) is impenetrable in my opinion, but there is [some](http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF_Tutorial) [good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) ELF format [information](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1060) out there. Try to find it.

If you have the [`musl libc`](http://www.musl-libc.org/) installed, or can install it, doing the same experiments as above on a simple executable compiled with musl libc can be very informative. Even something as complex as dynamic linking can have two different, working implementations on the same operating system.

Comment: Additionally, today's `Linux`systems support [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)